# Selenium two buttons with same xpath. Unable to click the one I need

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing, webdriver

There are two "EXPORT" buttons on the web page I am testing.
I am able to click the first using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.//text(),'EXPORT')]").click()
```

the driver then choses a dropdown and another div appears, again with an EXPORT button.

[image: Div of second EXPORT elements]

My code error when trying to execute:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.//text(),'EXPORT')]").click()
```

for this element is:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1824, 89). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)

So it says it is unable to  click the first EXPORT button and the second one would get the click.
I've tried modifying my xpath expression to:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[class()='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary' and (.//text(),'EXPORT')]").click()
```

and a bunch of other attempts, but each time it is unable to locate. I want to be able to click the second EXPORT button (in the button class snippet shown in the pic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate between these two **buttons** with the help of xpath indexing.

Sample below :-

```
(//span[text()='EXPORT']/..)[1]
```

and for second button :-

```
(//span[text()='EXPORT']/..)[2]
```

and for this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
> element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point
> (1824, 89). Other element would receive the click: ... (Session info:
> chrome=92.0.4515.107)

I would suggest you to open browser in full screen mode when it's launched.

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

or probably, you can use ActionChain as well :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[text()='EXPORT']/..)[2]")).click().perform()
```

**Update 1 :-**

You can use `find_elements` as well to store all the web element and then try to click the one you want.

```
all_export_button = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='EXPORT']/..")
#to click on first 
all_export_button[0].click()

#to click on Second 
all_export_button[1].click()
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have the window maximised. As for the indexing my error using:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='EXPORT'][2]").click()
is:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='EXPORT'][2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)

Comment: Is Page URL public  ? and I do see, you are using `("//span[text()='EXPORT'][2]")` which looks incorrect, what I have suggested (see above is) `(//span[text()='EXPORT']/..)[2]` so you can use it like this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[text()='EXPORT']/..)[2]").click()`

Comment: Thank you, there's an alternative as well to do this, please see update 1 section above.